# Where can I get Mix 09 slides from?

Tags: asp.net

I saw a site with all the slides (as ppt/pptx) of Mix09. Unfortunately I cannot remember the site address.

Does anyone know where to get these slides from? I've looked everywhere but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [Download MIX09 Sessions and Watch Offline](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/03/20/download-mix09-sessions-and-watch-offline.aspx)

It seems there is both a video and a link to download the slides *(as .pptx)*, for each session.

I have tried to download three random slides ; one of those was in 404 ; so not all slides might be downloadable... But, with a bit of luck, the ones that interest you will ^^

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you have some of them on [slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?lang=en&submit=post&q=+mix09&commit=search)